# SWIFT: Could not insert new outlet connection: Could not find class named ViewController in the language Swift

Tags: ios, swift

Please help. I can't seem to connect any outlets to viewcontroller. It used to work, but it doesn't anymore? I tried refreshing and everything, but no luck. [image]

Comment: From my experience, restart Xcode may help...

Comment: doesn't work. I tried this a couple times!

Comment: Check that the class of the ViewController in IB is set correctly.

Comment: Got it. Embarrassingly, I was trying to link a ViewController file from another location and didn't realize it. Wasted so much time and it was such a trivial mistake!